# Media html not rendering in blocks

Tags: blocks, media

I'm experiencing an issue on multiple sites where (image) media aren’t appearing in blocks despite working fine in node fields.

I first thought it only happened to me when using the linkicon module, but since then i created a custom block type for image blocks (using entity reference media fields) and the same thing happens, ie. the html renders nothing:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

There's no problem rendering the fields in nodes on the same sites using the exact same display settings.

I've checked both the media, block and block_content logs and they show no errors.

My setup:

- Drupal 8.9.7
- Barrio 5.1.3
- Local environment running on ddev
- Remote environment running on cloudways

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a conflict with the [songkick](https://drupal.org/project/songkick) module. I'm a maintainer  so I'll make sure the issue is handled and post further updates in the issue cue on Drupal.org [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/songkick/issues/3180869).